# How can I save kinect skeleton data into a file?

Tags: c#, c++, kinect, kinect-sdk

I was able to do this in the Kinect SDK beta 3, but I haven't developed for Kinect since and a lot seems to have changed.

I want to save each joint as a variable and write those values to a .csv file that I can parse through later. (Using c# preferably, but I can work with the c++ version as well)

**Question**

-What do I need to call to be able to get numerical values for each of the joints?

Any help would be appriciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Skeleton` data is just a series of `Joint` collections, containing X/Y/Z coordinates.  You can save them and write them just like any other type of object.

Getting the value of a `Joint` is shown in multiple examples provided by Microsoft for the [Kinect for Windows Samples](http://kinectforwindows.codeplex.com/).  Please explore those examples to gain a basis for working with the latest Kinect SDK.

Here is a basic callback to parse the `SkeletonFrame` and work with individual skeletons:

```
private void OnSkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
    {
        if (skeletonFrame == null || skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength == 0)
            return;

        // resize the skeletons array if needed
        if (_skeletons.Length != skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength)
            _skeletons = new Skeleton[skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];

        // get the skeleton data
        skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(_skeletons);

        foreach (var skeleton in _skeletons)
        {
            // skip the skeleton if it is not being tracked
            if (skeleton.TrackingState != SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
                continue;

            // print the RightHand Joint position to the debug console
            Debug.Writeline(skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight]);
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, the [Kinect Toolbox](http://kinecttoolbox.codeplex.com/) comes with functions that allow you to record and replay all 3 of the streams.